# Random string more than one IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to show the result in diffrent css. Here is the html:

```
<div class="yellow" id="studentID"></div>

<div class="red" id="studentID"></div>

<div class="blue" id="studentID"></div>

<div class="bllack" id="studentID"></div>
```

Here is the JS

```
function randString(x){
    var s = "";
    while(s.length<x&&x>0){
        var r = Math.random();
        s+= String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(r*26) + (r>0.5?97:65));
    }
    return s;
}

document.getElementById("studentID").innerHTML = randString(10);
```

I have spend more than 4 hours to find out the solution. No fix..

Why the random string only display in one DIV, how to get random string display in all DIV. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give multiple elements the same ID, use a class instead, and target your elements by class name.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("the-class");
```

This returns an array, and you can iterate over it to affect the individual elements.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("studentID");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = randString(10);
}
```

JSBin : http://jsbin.com/buqemafizi/1/

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be unique.  You should only have one element with an ID on the page. If you have multiple, your jquery will use the first one it finds.

You should apply the same class to all of the elements you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use that code.

```
 $('div').each(function () {
   $(this).attr('id', 'div' + 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6877));
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sv3399o7/6/)

Hope it helps you